# Instantiate multiple images javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**PROBLEM**
My problem is basically I want to create multiple images and draw them to a canvas. But the problem is I don't want to create A LOT of variable like for example to create an image I would do.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'img.png';
//I'm trying to prevent from having to use this line multiple times.
```

I don't really know what it's called so I couldn't do a thorough search on stackoverflow but if you do know what it is please point me to that and I'll be sure to look at it.

So do you guys know of any way efficient/fast way of doing this without having to create a dozen of variable. Because I'll be loading like 20+ Images or so.

**EXTRA QUESTION**
What is the proper name for this thing I'm trying to ask? Is it 'Create Object', Instantiate, or what?

Comment: You could use an array to hold all your img objects. iterate over it to drawimages on canvas.

Comment: @fubbe Okay thanks! I'll be sure to try that.

Comment: @fubbe Wait umm can you show me code for it? Because I'm actually kinda confused. Is it like `var imgArray = ['img1.png']` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the correct term is to instantiate it, or that the object is an instance of the class.  Here is an example of an array of image objects.

```
    var imgArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
         imgArray.push(new Image());
         imgArray[imgArray.length - 1].src = 'img.png';
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it supports images with different sources. And thanks for letting me know about the correct term. :)

Comment: It can.  It just depends on what you want and how the image files are named.  If possible, name them img1.png, img2.png, etc and then use .src = 'img' + i + '.png'.  Otherwise you'll just have to pull out the .src = portion and set them individually.

Comment: @nerdyguy Thanks for sharing! I will be sure to try that out. Any feedback on how to improve my question to not get down voted? Honestly don't know what I did wrong that it would get down voted.

Comment: One reason why questions sometimes get voted down is because they ask "how do I..."  A lot of the users are very unfriendly to that kind of question.  Most prefer the question to be more along the lines of "I'm trying to do ___ but I get the following error.  Here is my code so far.  D you know what is wrong?"  But even then they get voted down sometimes.  Honestly, SO isn't the friendliest place in the world.

Comment: Okay thanks! I will be sure to keep that in mind next time. Thank you very much for your kindness.